# Cross domain Ajax JSON POST support against RESTful WCF service using transportCredentialOnly security

Tags: javascript, wcf, authentication, rest, cross-domain

I've posted before on this subject, but after a year of getting on with other things, I've managed to get into a pickle once again. I'll try and give a brief overview of the scenario and the current attempts to make things work:

- IIS web server hosting HTML, JS etc. on host: *iis.mycompany.com* (referred to as *foo*)
- WCF RESTful web services hosted via a Windows Service on host: *wcf.mycompany.com* (referred to as *bar*)

The Javascript served from *foo* works by making RESTful ajax calls (`GET` or `POST` depending on the action) to the WCF services on *bar*, obviously these are cross domain calls as they aren't on the same host.

The Javascript uses the jQuery (1.7.2) framework to manipulate the DOM and perform ajax calls to *bar*, the expected content type for `POSTS` is `JSON`, and the response from `GETS` is expected to be `JSON` too (application/json).

*Bar* has it's WCF services configured using `TransportCredentialOnly` as the security mode and the transport client credentail type is `NTLM`, so only authed users to contact the services.

CORS Support has been added to *bar's* WCF services using an extension to WCF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

We have added additional headers and modfied some that the post already contained based on numerous internet articles:

```
property.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type");
property.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
property.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "172800");
property.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://iis.mycompany.com");
property.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
property.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Sites giving information on enabling CORS suggest that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header should be set to `"*"` however, this is not possible in our case as we make jQuery ajax calls using the following setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: "false",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

As it turns out you cannot use `"*"` for the accepted origin when you are using `"withCredentials"` in the ajax call:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

> "Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server
>   must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding."

Currently in our development lab, this doesn't matter as we can hard code the requests to the IIS (foo) server URL.

The main problem now appears to be attempting `POST` requests (`GET` is working using the above configuration). When the browser attempts the `POST` process, it first sends an `OPTIONS` header to the server requesting allowed `OPTIONS` for the subsequent post. This is where we would like to see the headers we've configured in the CORS Support WCF extension being passed back, however we aren't getting that far; before the response comes  back as *"401 Unauthorized"*, I believe this is to do with the transport security binding configuration requesting NTLM, but I'm not sure.

Also, I'm not very experienced with this, but I haven't seen much information about `POST` using `application/json` content type as opposed to `text/plain` when performing cross domain requests.

I know that people will probably suggest `JSONP` as the one true solution, I'm not against different approaches, indeed I encourage anyone to suggest best practices as it would help others reading this question later. However, please attempt to answer the question before suggestion alternatives to it.

Many thanks in advance for anyone who contributes.

peteski
:)

**UPDATE:**

It appears that Chrome (20.x.x) doesn't suffer the problem of not negotiating NTLM to retrieve the `OPTIONS` header response from the server, but Firefox (13.0.1) does.

We've also noticed that someone has already posted a bug up on the Firefox forum, which we've added information to:

http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751552

**Please vote for this bug to be fixed on the bugzilla site!**

Using the following code, we can watch the network trace to see Firefox failing and Chrome working fine:

```
var url = "http://myWebServiceServer/InstantMessagingService/chat/message/send";
var data = '{ "remoteUserUri" : "sip:foo.bar@mydomain.com", "message" : "This is my message" }';            
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();                     
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.withCredentials = true;
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                   
request.send(data);                     
console.log(request);
```

On a separate note, IE8 doesn't support the `XMLHttpRequest` for cross domain calls, favouring it's own magical `XDomainRequest` object, so we've got some work to do in changing the client side code to handle IE8 vs the world cases. (Thanks IE8).

*/me crosses fingers that Mozilla fix the Firefox bug.*

**UPDATE 2:**

After some digging it appears that IE8's `XDomainRequest` cannot be used to make cross domain requests where NTLM must be negotiated, this basically means that the security on our WCF binding can't be used thanks to limitations in a web browser.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

> "No authentication or cookies will be sent with the request"

So, I guess we've taken this as far as it is going to go for now.. It looks like we're going to have to create our own custom token authentication and pass it across to the WCF service in a cookie, or in IE8's case, `POST` it with the JSON. The WCF service will then have to handle decrypting the data and using that instead of the `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` we previously had access to with NTLM auth.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you would rather have the problem itself addressed, but you may consider using a "reverse proxy."

I don't know what technologies you are using, but we use Apache web server and have a Java RESTful API running on a different server that required authentication. For a while, we messed with JSONP and CORS, but were not satisfied.

In the end, we setup an Apache Reverse Proxy and it worked miracles. The web browser believes it is communicating with its own domain and acts appropriately. The RESTful API doesn't know it is being used via a proxy. Therefore, everything just works. And Apache does all the magic.

Hopefully, all web servers have a feature like Apache's reverse proxy.
Here is some documentation on the feature: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

All we had to do is ensure the mod_proxy module was installed, then add the following lines to our Apache config file:

```
ProxyPass /restapi http://restfulserver.com/restapi
ProxyPassReverse /restapi http://restfulserver.com/restapi
```

Then restart the web server and voila!